# My PC shuts down everytime I open my Yahoo Messenger

Tags: shutdown

Whenever I open my [Yahoo Messenger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Messenger) or any installed games my PC shuts down. Error says it is caused by the file `nv4_disp`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a video card driver issue.

Try the steps here: http://www.christopherjason.com/personal-computing/nvidia-nv4disp-problem/

Comment: Thank you Mr. Todd for the link and for replying. *smile* I will check it out and let my pc technician read the link as well. 
Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Besides the device driver, it may be insufficient power from your power supply.

Was your video card upgraded from the original to a gaming card?

Does your NVIDIA card have an external power plug that is plugged in?

What video card do you have, and what are your power supply ratings and manufacturer?

**EDIT:** To find out your video card, right-click on the desktop, select Properties, Settings tab, then look at the contents of the dropdown under "Display:".

Comment: Thank you Kmarsh for your reply. *smile* 
With regards to your questions I really don't have any idea. I have to check with my pc technician about these. He isn't available this week thus I went online to look for answers.